# Trying to build a function for vlookup for fixed data range

Tags: vba, function, vlookup

I'm trying to create a inbuilt function in VBA for vlookup wherein user does not need to select (table_array,column_index no,exact match) values as those are fix.

Tried to create below mentioned code but not working

```
Public Sub Lookupautomate()

Dim dtype As Range
Set dtype = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
Dim datarange As Range
Set datarange = Range("D:E")
Dim vvalue As String
Function get_data_type(dtype) As String

vvalue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(dtype, datarange, 2, 0)
get_data_type = vvalue

End Function

End Sub
```

I'm expecting that user just need to tell the input or the lookup value and my inbuilt function tells the exact value to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Option Explicit
Function get_data_type() As String

    Dim vvalue As String
    Dim dtype As Range
    Set dtype = Application.ThisCell.Offset(0, -1)

    Dim datarange As Range
    Set datarange = Range("D:E")

    vvalue = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(dtype, datarange, 2, 0)
    get_data_type = vvalue

End Function
```

Thought the offset 1 column behind means the function must always be placed on the same column.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for, however, has a drawback, wherein it works only for single cell but if i have to drag this to the multiple cells wont work, pls suggest if something can be done to make it dynamic

Comment: @user11992528 edited my answer, give it a try. If it works for you, please remember to mark the answer as correct.